# Querying MySQL nested json field and returning a subset of the json

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I have the following row:

| id | product_logs | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | <json string, see below> | 2022-07-13 07:13:00 |

Example json data:

```json
{
    "products": [
        {
            "logs": [{
                "log_time": "2022-07-13 01:30:00",
                "log_type": "manual",
                "log_info": "some text"
            }],
            "product_id": 123,
            "time": "2022-07-12 01:30:00"
        }, 
        {
            "logs": [],
            "product_id": 124,
            "time": "2022-07-13 01:31:00"
        }
    ]
}
```

E.g. searching for `product_id` 124, it should return the whole row, but the json field only contain the object that was matched:

| id | product_logs | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | `{"logs":[],"product_id":124,"time":"2022-07-13 01:31:00"}` | 2022-07-13 07:13:00 |

It would also be fine if the resulting output contains the original "shape" of the json:

```json
{
    "products": [
        {
            "logs": [],
            "product_id": 124,
            "time": "2022-07-13 01:31:00"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: What is MySQL version precisely?

Comment: @akina MySQL 5.7

Comment: On 5.7 the task cannot be solved as single query in general. You need iterative stored procedure which will parse your JSON, process it and reconstruct the desired output. Or, when the max. amount of objects in the array exists, you may use generated base numbers table...

Comment: I see, what if i only want the matched object without the rest of the row's column?

Comment: *what if i only want the matched object* But you must scan all objects. Even when you need only one of them.

Comment: I see... okay understood

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT test.id, 
       test.created_at, 
       JSON_OBJECT('products', JSON_ARRAYAGG(jsontable.log_data))
FROM test
CROSS JOIN JSON_TABLE(test.product_logs,
                      '$.products[*]' COLUMNS (log_data JSON PATH '$')) jsontable
WHERE jsontable.log_data->'$.product_id' = 124
GROUP BY 1,2
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=26541a1e241be02680ba97a78f0791c2

Comment: hey sorry I didn't mention earlier, but I'm running on mysql 5.7